# Why is my code writing the full path of the doc ID in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

How can I write the document ID alone instead of the full path? Currently my code is inserting `users/pdqr4LyHzbuGle0e8sCr`. I'd rather it insert `pdqr4LyHzbuGle0e8sCr`.

```
var collUsersRef: CollectionReference = db.collection("users")
val doc = collUsersRef.document()
var data: HashMap<String, Any> = hashMapOf(
                        "docID" to doc
                        , "email" to email
                        , "username" to user
                        , "createDate" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                        , "modifiedDate" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
                        , "stat" to 1
                    )

 doc.set(data)
```

Comment: Suggest you clarify the question.  The code doesn't explicitly mentioned any "document ID".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#getId()) property (java getter `getId()`) of the [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) object `doc`:

```
"docID" to doc.id
```